# How to select 1 random elements for each category

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I try to make a "getThreeWorks" method with Laravel. Each view post to its 'orientation'. It is stored in the same table. For example, "Work 1 has the web orientation, Work 2 has the 2D orientation and Work 3 has the 3D orientation".

At the end of each post, I would like to propose a link to 3 other works (in a random order).

So I would like a link to a work that has the "web" orientation, another that has the "2D" orientation and one that has the "3D" orientation.

I can't get SQL query at all. Can you help me ? Thank you !

```
public function getThreeWorks()
{
    $workFrom3D = Work::where('orientation', '3D')->inRandomOrder->limit(1)->get();
    $workFrom2D = Work::where('orientation', '2D')->inRandomOrder->limit(1)->get();
    $workFromWeb = Work::where('orientation', 'web')->inRandomOrder->limit(1)->get();
}
```

Comment: Did you try someting?

Comment: Yes, I edit my question

Comment: $workFrom3D = Work::where('orientation', '3D')->inRandomOrder->first();

Comment: Thank you @Scott but I can't return the 3 values

Comment: You want one from each correct? Are you looking for something more optimized? Just do the three individual and return each to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you remove the limit(1) and instead use a group by orientation? Then you get one of each.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new collection with your current code.

```
$work = collect([$workFrom3D, $workFrom2D, $workFromWeb]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood, you want show some "posts" on footer of each post, right ? you can try this:

```
public function getThreeWorks()
{
$workFrom3D = Work::where('orientation', '3D')->get();
$workFrom2D = Work::where('orientation', '2D')->get();
$workFromWeb = Work::where('orientation', 'web')->get();


$randomFrom3d  = $workFrom3D->random();
$workFrom2D = $workFrom2D->random();
$workFromWeb = $workFromWeb->random();
}
```

also, you should include one more condition on your where, to avoid repeat the same post on page where will show this list, like:

```
$workFromWeb = Work::where('orientation', 'web')
                ->where('post_id','!=', $actualPostId)->get();
```